# Not seeing changes made to page.xml or local.xml

Tags: theme, javascript

I don't understand what's going on here. I have a theme in:

`app\design\frontend\THEME_NAME\default\layout`

I've tried adding a JS files to both `page.xml` and `local.xml` but when I refresh the page I cannot see the file I've added.

In fact, no changes to the `page.xml` or `local.xml` files are being reflected when I refresh the page. I can see other JS files being added, and even if I change those then the changes aren't being seen in the source code.

What could be possibly going wrong?

Comment: You may have APC running or another server based cache. Have you refreshed all of this?

Comment: Crap. I inherited this project, and I only have access to the raw files and Magento backend. Is there anything I can do from there?

Comment: @brentwpeterson There's something in `local.xml.additional` regarding `full_page_cache` and `cache`. How can I clear these? :-/

Comment: You should post your version in the future, you mention Full Page Cache, are you running Enterprise?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it was my server cache. By deleting the contents of `/var/cache` on the server my changes were seen.